# Excel VBA for select next 100 cells in column below active cell

Tags: vba, excel

As above I'm trying to find an Excel macro to select and copy next 100 cells below from active cell in a column.

Comment: Post the code you have tried and explain what happens when you run it.

Comment: Thanks Blackwood....I found some code this morning for select 1000 and modded that. Works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the macro recorder and ask it to use relative cell addresses.

Comment: Ahhhh I was trying to figure out how to do that when I was trying to record my own macro. Cool. Thanks